# NSCollectionView how to drag to arrange view Items ?

Tags: xcode, swift, nscollectionview

I try to use a NSCollectionView but I want to let user to rearrange any item with drag and drop. but I don't know where i should start.

Until now, all I have in mind is to use NSCollectionViewDelegate... 
Here is something I think I can use, but i don't have any idea what I must to do next.

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: NSCollectionView, acceptDrop draggingInfo: NSDraggingInfo, index: Int, dropOperation: NSCollectionViewDropOperation) -> Bool {
    println("Entered")

    return true
}

func collectionView(collectionView: NSCollectionView, canDragItemsAtIndexes indexes: NSIndexSet, withEvent event: NSEvent) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: check this opensource https://github.com/ra1028/RACollectionViewReorderableTripletLayout

Comment: This is awesome, but, again i forgeted to mention I need this for OS X not iOs.